# Blob size limit to assign Audio HTML src in mobile navigators?

Tags: javascript, blob, html5-audio, wav

Mobile browser launch an error if I assign a dynamically SRC of an Audio HTML Element bigger than 500000000 KBytes (48 MGBytes). No problem if the blob is lower that 500000000 KBytes.

Its about 13 minutes of mono audio. I need 30 minutes.

Is possible to enlarge it?

I am generating waves sound (aleatory noise for this case) with javascript and saving in a **Uint8Array buffer**.

```
  var megaBytes = 48; //50331648 KBytes
  var bytes = megaBytes*1024*1024;

  var uint8 = new Uint8Array(bytes);
  for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
    uint8[i] = getRandomInt(0,100) + 128;
  }
```

Then I need to create the WAV Base64 array:

```
    var arrBytesFinal = getWavBytes( uint8, {
      isFloat: false,      // floating point or 16-bit integer
      numChannels: 1,     // Mono. 2 - Stereo    
      sampleRate: 32000, // Bitrate
    })
```

After I create an audio/wav type Blob and assign to my HTML audioControl **as src**.

```
    var myBlob = new Blob( [arrBytesFinal] , { type : 'audio/wav; codecs=0' });
    var readerBlob = new FileReader();
    readerBlob.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
        var myAudioFinal = readerBlob.result.toString(); 
        audioControl.src = myAudioFinal; //HERE THE NAVIGATOR PROBLEM.
        playButton.disabled = false;
    });
    readerBlob.readAsDataURL(myBlob);
```

Comment: Just do like `audioControl.src = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)` instead. DataURLs can only be so large.

Comment: @StackSlave The data:// URL itself can be bigger (about 512MB in v8 browsers), but it takes definitely more memory than a blob:// URI (about 3 times+). To OP, for what you are doing use the Web Audio API, you can generate the sound directly, with no memory pressure. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Advanced_techniques#the_noise_%E2%80%94_random_noise_buffer_with_biquad_filter

Comment: @Kaiido. Thanks! but I can not use Web Audio API because the navigator turn off the sound if navigator is minimized or mobile suspended.

Answer (score -1):

Some notes:

- Make sure that your WAV is really a WAVE file (44-byte header according to RIFF format etc).
- Using `readerBlob.result.toString();` will not give you audio data (is text from byte values).

Try this version (untested) of your last shown code:

```
var myBlob = new Blob( [arrBytesFinal] , { type : 'audio/wav;' });
var readerBlob = new FileReader();
readerBlob.addEventListener("loadend", function( evt ) {
    var myAudioFinal = new Uint8Array( readerBlob.result );
    //var myAudioFinal = new Uint8Array( evt.target.result ); //# or try this way...
    audioControl.src = myAudioFinal; //HERE THE NAVIGATOR PROBLEM.
    playButton.disabled = false;
      
});
readerBlob.readAsArrayBuffer(myBlob);
```